# How to use DOM XML to pass html and find a span

Tags: php, html, xml, dom

I have some html input from the user, I want to find all occurences of

```
<span class="widget-tag"></span>
```

This is what I have so far:

```
$d = new DOMDocument();
$d->loadHTML($html);
```

I don't know which function to use next.

Any help would be great.

Thanks

Jason

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After that try...

```
$xpath = new DOMXpath($d);
$elements = $xpath->query("//div[class='widget-tag']");
```

This will return a DOMNodeList of the matching elements.

Comment: actually it will not, you'll have to use `[@class ...` to search for node attributes. And I would replace the `div` with `span` or `*` as that's what's given in the question example.